# whats the problem with rarcrack?

Tags: password-recovery, rarcrack

I have installed Rarcrack but whats the issue with it I am not getting . here the code of the terminal

```
root@ubuntu:~/sec# sudo apt-get install rarcrack
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rarcrack:i386 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@ubuntu:~/sec# rarcrack english.zip
-bash: /usr/bin/rarcrack: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:~/sec# which rarcrack
/usr/bin/rarcrack
root@ubuntu:~/sec# rarcrack english.zip
-bash: /usr/bin/rarcrack: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:~/sec#
```

Comment: What do `ls -l /usr/bin/rarcrack` and `ls -L /usr/bin/rarcrack` show? Have you tried `sudo apt-get --reinstall install rarcrack`?  BTW: you seem to be running as root, no `sudo` needed.

Comment: That's not a package from the Ubuntu archives. Also you should know by now not to use the user root directly and what the sudo command is for.

Comment: Possibly broken package from 3rd party site that isn't in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: The package you installed is 32-bit. Is your system 64-bit? Maybe some 32-bit libraries are missing.

Comment: @EricCarvalho what I am supposed to do then ?

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev build-essential
wget http://surfnet.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/rarcrack/rarcrack-0.2.tar.bz2    tar -xjf rarcrack-0.2.tar.bz2
cd rarcrack-0.2
make
sudo make install
rarcrack something.rar --type rar
```

Beware you have to have unrar-free installed and not unrar package to be working. If is the case

```
sudo apt-get remove unrar
sudo apt-get install unrar-free
```